# Only Local git commands are woking not remote commands

Tags: git, ubuntu

Local git commands like `git status`, `git brach` etc are working. But Remote commands like `git fetch`, `git pull` etc are not working.

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall, internet is working fine. Any pointers what could be the issue?

Comment: Please paste the error message into your question

Comment: This sounds like the remote of your Git repository is not set. How did you initialise your Git repository? Did you simply created a local repository using `git init` or did you clone a repository with `git clone`?

Could you provide more context of what you already did and which exact error(s) you encounter?

Comment: So, as it turned out, there was some issue on the bitbucket's servers. I wanted to delete this questions, but stackoverflow is not allowing as there are answers already.

Answer (score 2):

you may try to set up your remote. You can do this via:
`git remote add [-t <branch>] [-m <master>] [-f] [--[no-]tags] [--mirror=<fetch|push>] <name> <url>`

When trying to push, you should specify the upstream for the remote repository, via command:
`git push --set-upstream master`

you can check [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote)